# Silence WCast-function-type on a function structure

Tags: c, casting, warnings, compiler-warnings

I have the following warning :

```
cast between incompatible function types from ‘int (*)(pile *)’ {aka ‘int (*)(struct pile *)’} to ‘void (*)(void *)’ [-Wcast-function-type]
```

I don't have any idea of how I can fix this warning.

Structure

```c
typedef struct conteneur_sommets {
  void *donnees;
  int (*est_vide)(void *);
  void (*ajouter)(void *, int);
  void (*supprimer)(void *);
  int (*choisir)(void *);
  void (*detruire)(void *);
} conteneur_sommets;
```

associated function

```c
conteneur_sommets *cs_creer_pile(int n)
{
  conteneur_sommets cs = {.donnees   = pile_creer(n),
              .est_vide  = (int (*)(void *))        pile_est_vide,
              .ajouter   = (void (*)(void *, int))  pile_empiler,
              .supprimer = (void (*)(void *))       pile_depiler, <- warning cast
              .choisir   = (int (*)(void *))        pile_sommet,
              .detruire  = (void (*)(void *))       pile_detruire};
  return cs_creer(&cs);
}

void cs_supprimer(conteneur_sommets *cs)
{
  cs->supprimer(cs->donnees);
}
```

Comment: Try `(void (*)())` to not provide signature info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While suppressing the warning completely can sometimes be usefull, it is better in general to fix the issue at the code level. 
The issue here is that your declarations are wrong which is reason the warning is triggered in the first place.
First avoid to combine the definition of a struct/union and the declaration of the `typedef` alias. It is better to separate them, this way you can, if necessary separate declaration and definition.

```
typedef struct conteneur_sommets conteneur_sommets;
```

This creates the alias `conteneur_sommets` to the **opaque** structure `struct conteneur_sommets`. This is also called a forward declaration. The forward declaration is generally put in the header file.

Now we can define the structure

```
struct conteneur_sommets {
    void *donnees;
    int (*est_vide)(conteneur_sommets *);
    void (*ajouter)(conteneur_sommets *, int);
    void (*supprimer)(conteneur_sommets *);
    int (*choisir)(conteneur_sommets *);
    void (*detruire)(conteneur_sommets *);
};
```

This way you don't need to cast the function pointer and conserve type checks if it is of the right signature.

```
conteneur_sommets cs = {.donnees   = pile_creer(n),
          .supprimer = pile_depiler};
```

---

Secondly
A thing that is seldom realized by C programmers is that one can define typedef aliases of function prototypes, not function pointers but directly of prototypes. This can sometime really make the code much more readable even if quite unusual. Let me give you an example with your code:

```
typedef int  est_vide_fn (conteneur_sommets *);
typedef void ajouter_fn  (conteneur_sommets *, int);
typedef void supprimer_fn(conteneur_sommets *);
typedef int  choisir_fn  (conteneur_sommets *);
typedef void detruire_fn (conteneur_sommets *);
```

this declares five function prototype type definitions.

the structure can now be declared as

```
struct conteneur_sommets {
    void *donnees;
    est_vide_fn  *est_vide;
    ajouter_fn   *ajouter;
    supprimer_fn *supprimer;
    choisir_fn   *choisir;
    detruire_fn  *detruire;
};
```

Your `cs_supprimer` functions prototype can be declared by

```
supprimer_fn cs_supprimer;
```

and its implementation is defined as before

```
void cs_supprimer(conteneur_sommets *cs)
{
    cs->supprimer(cs->donnees);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have silenced it by having a pragma macro

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcast-function-type"

// some affected code

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this through a 3rd party dependency ([Cyrus SASL](https://www.cyrusimap.org/sasl/)), which declares the following struct to hold a callback to user code

```c
/*
 * Extensible type for a client/server callbacks
 *  id      -- identifies callback type
 *  proc    -- procedure call arguments vary based on id
 *  context -- context passed to procedure
 */
/* Note that any memory that is allocated by the callback needs to be
 * freed by the application, be it via function call or interaction.
 *
 * It may be freed after sasl_*_step returns SASL_OK.  if the mechanism
 * requires this information to persist (for a security layer, for example)
 * it must maintain a private copy.
 */
typedef struct sasl_callback {
    /* Identifies the type of the callback function.
     * Mechanisms must ignore callbacks with id's they don't recognize.
     */
    unsigned long id;
    int (*proc)(void);   /* Callback function.  Types of arguments vary by 'id' */
    void *context;
} sasl_callback_t;
```

The problem is, that the specific type signature of the callback function differs depending on which callback it is, as is stated in

```
int (*proc)(void);   /* Callback function.  Types of arguments vary by 'id' */
```

Attempts to use this from my code inevitably cause `cast-function-type` warning.

### Robust warning-suppression macros

To suppress warnings like this, it is helpful to start by defining robust warning-suppression machinery through preprocessor macros. Here's [what Facebook Folly does (licensed under ASL 2.0)](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/c71af83adb058929e841532c7e0fa523f8a3be80/folly/CPortability.h#L280).

```c
// Generalize warning push/pop.
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
// Clang & GCC
#define FOLLY_PUSH_WARNING _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push")
#define FOLLY_POP_WARNING _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")
#define FOLLY_GNU_DISABLE_WARNING_INTERNAL2(warningName) #warningName
#define FOLLY_GNU_DISABLE_WARNING(warningName) \
  _Pragma(                                     \
      FOLLY_GNU_DISABLE_WARNING_INTERNAL2(GCC diagnostic ignored warningName))
#ifdef __clang__
#define FOLLY_CLANG_DISABLE_WARNING(warningName) \
  FOLLY_GNU_DISABLE_WARNING(warningName)
#define FOLLY_GCC_DISABLE_WARNING(warningName)
#else
#define FOLLY_CLANG_DISABLE_WARNING(warningName)
#define FOLLY_GCC_DISABLE_WARNING(warningName) \
  FOLLY_GNU_DISABLE_WARNING(warningName)
#endif
#define FOLLY_MSVC_DISABLE_WARNING(warningNumber)
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define FOLLY_PUSH_WARNING __pragma(warning(push))
#define FOLLY_POP_WARNING __pragma(warning(pop))
// Disable the GCC warnings.
#define FOLLY_GNU_DISABLE_WARNING(warningName)
#define FOLLY_GCC_DISABLE_WARNING(warningName)
#define FOLLY_CLANG_DISABLE_WARNING(warningName)
#define FOLLY_MSVC_DISABLE_WARNING(warningNumber) \
  __pragma(warning(disable : warningNumber))
#else
#define FOLLY_PUSH_WARNING
#define FOLLY_POP_WARNING
#define FOLLY_GNU_DISABLE_WARNING(warningName)
#define FOLLY_GCC_DISABLE_WARNING(warningName)
#define FOLLY_CLANG_DISABLE_WARNING(warningName)
#define FOLLY_MSVC_DISABLE_WARNING(warningNumber)
#endif
```

(Change the prefix from FOLLY_ to your own prefix when reusing the code).

This way, I can suppress the GCC/Clang warning, while still being able to compile on MSVC.

```c
PN_PUSH_WARNING
PN_GNU_DISABLE_WARNING("-Wcast-function-type")
static const sasl_callback_t pni_server_callbacks[] = {
    {SASL_CB_PROXY_POLICY, (int(*)(void)) pni_authorize, NULL},
    {SASL_CB_LIST_END, NULL, NULL},
};
PN_POP_WARNING
```

Answer (score 0):

`cast between incompatible function types from ‘int (*)(pile *)’ {aka ‘int (*)(struct pile *)’} to ‘void (*)(void *)’ [-Wcast-function-type]`

This warning means two function pointer's prototype is differ..

`supprimer` and `pile_depiler` has different prototype ( return value type and parameter type )

match two function's prototype then the warning will be disappear.
Simply you can do cast prototype but the result is not predictable.